# Don't apply highlighting on cursor

Tags: vim, line, highlight, text-cursor

I highlighted my *CursorLine* with

```
highlight CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=black ctermfg=yellow
```

I'd like to preserve the original highlighting for the cursor (black/white). I tried this settings:

```
highlight Cursor ctermbg=white ctermfg=black
```

which does not work.

How can I highlight the *CursorLine* without highlighting the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took a snoop through the vim source; there's no special handling for the cursor itself with respect to CursorLine highlighting.

I'm not clear about the problem you're trying to solve, can you elaborate?  There may be other ways to address it.

Comment: Normally, cursor is a black rectangle in the file and I'd like to preserve this color regardless I change highlight for *CursorLine*. If it's not possible, I will accept your answer too.

Comment: Ok, is that mainly to make it easier to see the character under the cursor?  Or so you can more easily locate the cursor in the line?  Or something else?

Comment: I wanted the cursor to have the color of surrounding lines, because the current line is highlighted. I wanted to try it, I don't know yet if it's useful or not.

Comment: If easily locating the cursor is the goal, you might find the `cursorcolumn` option useful when used with `cursorline`.  It adds a vertical equivalent to the row highlight.  Otherwise, I think it would be difficult to achieve what you want without modifying vim.

Comment: OK. It was not the goal, but I believe you that I would have to modify vim.